# substr gives empty string when string contains signs

Tags: php

I try to get a substring of a string that includes some special signs, and it gives me an empty string.
code:

```
$iii = "<img>";
echo substr($iii, 0, 2);
```

when i remove the '<' it works perfectly.
any suggestion why is that happening and how to fix it?

thx.

Comment: Works for me: `<i`, which version of PHP are you running? Any out of the ordinary config settings?

Comment: works for me. http://ideone.com/4Ooodv

Comment: `substr` works fine, view source to convince yourself. It's the browser that treats `<i` as a tag. Use `echo htmlspecialchars(...)` to see the real contents of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo htmlentities(substr($iii, 0, 2));
```

Comment: this is exactly what i have lookes for. solved the problem. thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you output to browser, and browser considers it to be html tag. Use htmlspecialchars() to escape < and > chars.

Comment: hello and thank you for your answer, i tried this and this works, also i have noticed that now it takes 4 chars to represent the <. but it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
$iii = "<img>";
echo htmlspecialchars(substr($iii, 0, 2));
```

Try this...